# Javascript detect size windows and execute new fonction

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to display one javascript slider but if the size is less that 825px the fonction to be disable I created one code but they don't work. I search here but i dont found any answer about that.
here my code

```
$(window).ready(function() {
var wi = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
var wi = $(window).width();
  if (wi < 825){

  } else {


     // Slide function
                var slideIndex = 1;
                showDivs(slideIndex);

                function plusDivs(n) {
                showDivs(slideIndex += n);
                }
                function showDivs(n) {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
                if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";  
                }
                x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                }
                }


}); 
});
```

thank you for any help the slide function work perfect but i dont arrive to detect the windows size.

Comment: Are you aware your code currently only runs when the window resizes? Maybe try checking the width after the page has finished loading instead?

Comment: I put the code at the end of page after footer and before body and heml tag I think is ok ?

Comment: You're loading your script at the right place, but any code inside `$(window).resize()` will only run on resize. Consider taking the code inside `resize()` and calling it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to do the slide, add a condition to return

```
function doSlide() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 825) {
    return
  }

  // Slide function
  ...your code
}
```

As people suggested, call it directly. Attach resize event if you want.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  doSlide()
  window.addEventListener('resize', doSlide)
}
```

Comment: sorry but am so null in javascript the second function $(window).ready i need to put after the first condition ?

Comment: function doSlide() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 825) {
    return
  } // Slide function
   
  
// END SLIDE    
}  
$(window).ready(function() {
  doSlide()
  window.addEventListener('resize', doSlide)
})

Comment: Hi Thomazella i put the code but dont wotk am not sure if i did correctly

Comment: I dont understand where i control the size of screen ?